# Is there any way to remove this white line next to a WinForms scrollbar?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, scrollbar, panel

I've noticed that the scrollbar on the `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` appears to have a white line going down the left-side of the vertical scrollbar.

[image: Vertical scrollbar]
.

[image: Vertical scrollbar zoomed in]
.

The horizontal scrollbar also has this (the white line appears above it):
[image: Horizontal scrollbar]
.

I've also noticed it with `DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraScrollableControl` when it's got `UseWindowsXPTheme` set to true, so I'm guessing it may be a system thing (as this is just an example, I haven't tagged this question with the DevExpress tag).

I've noticed that in the Visual Studio 2015 Options screen, it has an example of a Scrollbar with this white line (the one on the left), AND without it (the one on the right):
[image: VS2015 Options]
.

My question is: Is there any way to remove this white line from the scrollbar?  If so, how?  I know it may seem minor, but it's noticeable enough to be annoying.

I've tagged this question as both VB.NET and C# as I am happy to accept answers in either language.

Comment: Dose your application have `Application.EnableVisualStyles();`?

Comment: It seems to be a 3d highlight.  Not sure where you could set it to a flat style..

Comment: Adding a call to `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` as the first line in `InitializeComponent()` did not appear to have any effect.

Comment: Well looking at the code in the program.cs this shouldn't come as a surprise, right? It is more likely to influence it in the system settings, but imo this is a no-go for just about any case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after looking into things such as [handling the Paint event for a Scrollbar control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126980/handling-vscrollbar-paint-event), I eventually came up with an easier and simpler (but ultimately uncomfortable) solution: Cover it with a `Label` control!

This will do the trick for vertical and horizontal scrollbars for a `Panel`:

```
Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey =  Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion")
Dim operatingSystem As String = ""

If key IsNot Nothing
    operatingSystem = key.GetValue("ProductName")
End If

If operatingSystem.Contains("Windows 10")
    Dim verticalHiderLabel As New Label With {  .Location = New Point(Panel1.Right - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth-1, Panel1.Top+1),
                                                .Size = New Size(1, Panel1.Height - SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight-1)}

    Dim horizontalHiderLabel As New Label With {.Location = New Point(Panel1.Left+1, Panel1.Bottom - SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight-1),
                                                .Size = New Size(Panel1.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth-1, 1)}

    Me.Controls.Add(verticalHiderLabel)
    Me.Controls.Add(horizontalHiderLabel)
    verticalHiderLabel.BringToFront()
    horizontalHiderLabel.BringToFront()
End If
```

As I've not seen this issue on any other operating systems, I've added a check to try and ensure that it's only enabled on Windows 10, which unfortunately uses the registry, as I'm not sure there's a reliable way to do that check otherwise on Windows 10.

Obviously if someone's using a resizeable `Control` with scrollbars, they'll want to update the `Label` sizes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this unless you use your own custom controls for scrolling. This is just a 3D highlight effect on the scrollbar and the scrollbar does not have an override property to change its style to flat.

But here are some fancy custom scrollbars you can use.

[CodeProject: Scrolling Panel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226381/Scrolling-Panel)

[CodeProject: Cool Scrollbar - Scrollbar like Windows Media Player's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8557/Cool-Scrollbar-Scrollbar-like-Windows-Media-Player)

[CodeProject: How to skin scrollbars for Panels, in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C)

[CodeProject: Replace a Window's Internal Scrollbar with a customdraw scrollbar Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14724/Replace-a-Window-s-Internal-Scrollbar-with-a-custo)