# Handling VScrollbar Paint event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scrollbar, paintevent

I've been trying to handle the `Paint` event for a control on a form.  However the event never gets handled, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've created a very simple WinForms project to demonstrate this (I've included the generated designer code to show that there's nothing else there):

Form1.vb

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler VScrollBar1.Paint, AddressOf VScrollBar1_Paint
    End Sub

    Private Sub VScrollBar1_Paint (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim str As String = "test"
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(str)
    End Sub                              
End Class
```

Form1.Designer.vb

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.VScrollBar1 = New System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar()
        Me.SuspendLayout
        '
        'VScrollBar1
        '
        Me.VScrollBar1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(26, 56)
        Me.VScrollBar1.Name = "VScrollBar1"
        Me.VScrollBar1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(17, 80)
        Me.VScrollBar1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6!, 13!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 261)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.VScrollBar1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(false)

    End Sub
        Friend WithEvents VScrollBar1 As System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar

End Class
```

The event is never handled, but the control is drawn correctly.  What am I missing?

Comment: Scroll bars do not raise paint events. They are painted internally by the system. There is no facility for owner-drawing them. You ask for scrollbars, you get scrollbars. There is never a good reason to override the standard system appearance.

Comment: If you open the events list for the control you'll see there is no paint event.  you are trying to handle something that is not meant for you to mess with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, after spending a bit more time on this, I've discovered that all you need to do is call the [SetStyle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) method with the flag and value parameters set to `ControlStyles.userPaint` and `True`, respectively.

This method isn't public though, so reflection is needed in order to invoke it:

```
Dim methodInfo As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = VScrollBar1.GetType().GetMethod("SetStyle", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
methodInfo.Invoke(VScrollBar1, {ControlStyles.UserPaint, True})
```

I put the above code into the Form1_Load method above, just above the `AddHandler` line and it appears to work (I can handle the event).

Comment: As others have said...it's hidden from you for a reason.

Comment: Yes, you can hack around the protections that are in place to allow yourself to handle the event. But it still does not solve your problem. You cannot owner-draw a scroll bar control, which makes the ability to handle the Paint event completely pointless. About the only thing you can do to customize a scrollbar is handle the WM_CTLCOLOR message to change the background color. Otherwise, you will essentially have to build your own scrollbar control from scratch, which I *strongly* advise against. (As such, I've downvoted this answer because it is neither useful nor relevant.)

Comment: Regarding your 'neither useful nor relevant' comment, it was relevant to me, as it DOES directly answer my own question: I asked how to handle the Paint event.

As you disagree with the premise of the question in the first place, you should probably downvote the question, not the answer.  My reason for this odd question in the first place was because I was attempting to deal with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094955/is-there-any-way-to-remove-this-white-line-next-to-a-winforms-scrollbar

Comment: Also, utilising the functions in the `ScrollBarRenderer` class seem to reduce the difficulty of drawing a basic scrollbar, and handling the `Paint` event allows further changes to be made from there.  Of course, if it's getting really complicated, it may be worth making a new class that inherits `Scrollbar` and overriding the `OnPaint` method, however that might be a bit overkill in some scenarios, especially for what I was trying to do.